# Struct doesn't cache, but Class does

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, caching, struct

I have a flood limiter for image uploading:

```
public class FloodLimiter
{
    public static void OnImageUploaded(string ipAddress, int sizeBytes)
    {
        var dict = GetImageUploadFloodLimitDict();
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(ipAddress))
        {
            dict.Add(ipAddress, new ImageUploadLimits());
        }
        dict[ipAddress].OnFileUploaded(sizeBytes);
    }

    public static bool CanUploadImages(string ipAddress)
    {
        var dict = GetImageUploadFloodLimitDict();
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(ipAddress)) return true;
        return dict[ipAddress].BelowLimits;
    }

    private static readonly object FloodLimitLock = new object();
    /// <summary>
    /// Dictionary of IP's, and total images uploaded + total image size uploaded
    /// </summary>
    private static Dictionary<string, ImageUploadLimits> GetImageUploadFloodLimitDict()
    {
        const string cacheIndex = Settings.CachePrefix + "ImageUploadFloodLimiter";
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context.Cache[cacheIndex] == null)
        {
            lock (FloodLimitLock)
            {
                if (context.Cache[cacheIndex] == null)
                {
                    var dict = new Dictionary<string, ImageUploadLimits>();
                    context.Cache.Add(cacheIndex, dict, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Settings.ImageUpload.FloodLimitRecycleMinutes), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.AboveNormal, null);
                }
            }
        }
        return (Dictionary<string, ImageUploadLimits>)context.Cache[cacheIndex];
    }
}
```

If `ImageUploadLimits` is defined as:

```
private struct ImageUploadLimits
{
    private int _totalImagesUploaded;
    private int _totalBytesUploaded;
    public bool BelowLimits { get {
        return _totalImagesUploaded < Settings.ImageUpload.MaximumImagesCanUploadInPeriod && _totalBytesUploaded < (Settings.ImageUpload.MaximumImageUploadMbInPeriod * 1000000);
    }}

    public void OnFileUploaded(int sizeBytes)
    {
        _totalImagesUploaded ++;
        _totalBytesUploaded += sizeBytes;
    }
}
```

The cache never updates (it always returns 1 image uploaded).

If I define `ImageUploadLimits` as:

```
private class ImageUploadLimits
{
    private int _totalImagesUploaded;
    private int _totalBytesUploaded;
    public bool BelowLimits { get {
        return _totalImagesUploaded < Settings.ImageUpload.MaximumImagesCanUploadInPeriod && _totalBytesUploaded < (Settings.ImageUpload.MaximumImageUploadMbInPeriod * 1000000);
    }}

    public void OnFileUploaded(int sizeBytes)
    {
        _totalImagesUploaded++;
        _totalBytesUploaded += sizeBytes;
    }
}
```

It works just fine!

Why is the `struct` version not caching?  Is it something to do with `Structs` being passed byVal and `Classes` byRef?

Comment: You have just discovered why making mutable structs is a bad practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you read the struct from the dictionary, you get a copy of the struct. The changes that the `OnFileUploaded` method does to the values only affect the copy, not the original in the dictionary.

If you use a struct, you need to write the copy back to the dictionary:

```
ImageUploadLimits copy = dict[ipAddress];
copy.OnFileUploaded(sizeBytes);
dict[ipAddress] = copy;
```

When you use a class, you get a copy of the reference from the dictionary. There is still only one object, but two references to it.

---

Note: The terms *by reference* and *by value* refer to how parameters are passed. Parameters are always passed by value regardless if it is a struct or a class, unless you use the `ref` or `out` keyword. What's passed by value is either a copy of the struct or a copy of the reference to the object.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Guffa's answer: it is harder to confuse yourself if you use immutable structs, where methods that change the state return a new instance instead of modifying internal state.

This makes it more obvious to yourself (and anyone else reading the code), that you need to assign the returned value back to wherever you got it from:

```
struct ImageUploadLimits
{
    private readonly int _totalImagesUploaded;
    private readonly int _totalBytesUploaded;

    public ImageUploadLimits(int totalImagesUploaded, int totalBytesUploaded)
    {
        _totalImagesUploaded = totalImagesUploaded;
        _totalBytesUploaded = totalBytesUploaded;
    }

    public bool BelowLimits
    {
        get { return _totalImagesUploaded < Settings.ImageUpload.MaximumImagesCanUploadInPeriod && _totalBytesUploaded < (Settings.ImageUpload.MaximumImageUploadMbInPeriod * 1000000); }
    }

    public ImageUploadLimits WithAdditionalFileUpload(int sizeBytes)
    {
        return new ImageUploadLimits(_totalImagesUploaded + 1, _totalBytesUploaded + sizeBytes);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var limits = default(ImageUploadLimits);

dict.TryGetValue(ipAddress, out limits);
dict[ipAddress] = limits.WithAdditionalFileUpload(sizeBytes);
```